# Collision detection in my js platformer game. Can't stop the object, but detection works

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a platformer game, and I'm adding collision, but I'm not sure how to stop the object after collision is detected. This is my javascript, and I have a basic html document with a  tag. Could someone help me out with stopping an object after I detect collision? I feel like my solutions I've come up with are much to complicated.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
const characterImage = document.getElementById('character')
const level = 1
canvas.width = document.body.scrollWidth
canvas.height = document.body.scrollHeight

let time; // Current time
let prevTime = Date.now(); // Store previous time
let isGrounded; // Check if player is on the ground

class Main {
    constructor(x, y, w, h) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.w = w;
        this.h = h;
        this.lives = 3;
        this.speedX = 0;
        this.speedY = 0;
        this.gravity = .01;
        // this.gravitySpeed = 0;
        this.jumpSpeed = -1.5; // How fast to jump upwards
        this.dx = 0;
        this.dy = 0;
        this.centerX = canvas.width / 2;
        this.centerY = canvas.height / 2;
    }
    draw() {
        if (this.x <= -0) {
            this.x = -0
        }

        if (this.x >= canvas.width - 50) {
            this.x = canvas.width - 50
        }

        const player = {
            image: characterImage,
            x: this.x,
            y: this.y,
            w: 50,
            h: 50
        }

        const obstacle1 = {
            x: this.centerX,
            y: canvas.height - 100,
            w: 50,
            h: 50
        }

        const lava = {

        }

        const ground = {
            x: 0,
            y: canvas.height - 50,
            w: canvas.width,
            h: 50
        }
        //collision detection
        
        if (player.x < obstacle1.x + obstacle1.w &&
            player.x + obstacle1.w > obstacle1.x &&
            player.y < obstacle1.y + obstacle1.h &&
            player.y + player.h > obstacle1.y) {
            }
            


        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.fillStyle = '#9b7653'
        ctx.fillRect(ground.x, ground.y, ground.w, ground.h)
        ctx.closePath();

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.drawImage(player.image, player.x, player.y, player.w, player.h);
        ctx.closePath();

        //obstacles
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.fillStyle = '#df4759'
        ctx.fillRect(obstacle1.x, obstacle1.y, obstacle1.w, obstacle1.h);
        ctx.closePath();
    }

    newPos() {
        this.gravitySpeed += this.gravity;
        this.x += this.speedX;
    }

    update() {
        
        // Calculate how much time has passed since last update
        time = Date.now();
        const deltaTime = time - prevTime;

        // Update y-position based speed in y-direction
        // If we jump this.speed will be set to this.jumpSpeed
        this.y += this.speedY * deltaTime;
        // Gravity should always affect the player!
        // The ground check will make sure we don't fall through the floor
        this.y += this.gravity * deltaTime;
        // Make sure to reduce our player's speed in y by gravity!
        this.speedY += this.gravity * deltaTime;

        // Only allow the player to jump if he is on the ground
        if (controller1.up && isGrounded) {
            // Set the player y-speed to jump speed
            this.speedY = this.jumpSpeed;
        };

        if (controller1.right) {
            this.dx += 0.7
        };
        if (controller1.left) {
            this.dx -= 0.7
        };

        this.x += this.dx;
        // this.y += this.dy;
        this.dx *= 0.9;
        this.dy *= 0.9;

        // Ground check
        if (this.y >= canvas.height - 100) {
            this.y = canvas.height - 100;
            isGrounded = true;
        } else {
            isGrounded = false;
        }


        // Store the current time to use for calculation in next update
        prevTime = Date.now();
    }

}

class Controller {
    constructor() {
        this.up = false;
        this.right = false;
        this.down = false;
        this.left = false;

        let keyEvent = (e) => {
            if (e.code == "KeyW" || e.code == "ArrowUp" || e.code == "Space") {
                this.up = e.type == 'keydown'
            };
            if (e.code == "KeyD" || e.code == "ArrowRight") {
                this.right = e.type == 'keydown'
            };
            if (e.code == "KeyA" || e.code == "ArrowLeft") {
                this.left = e.type == 'keydown'
            };
        }

        addEventListener('keydown', keyEvent);
        addEventListener('keyup', keyEvent);
        addEventListener('mousemove', keyEvent)
    }
}

let main1 = new Main(50, canvas.height - 150, 50, 50)
let controller1 = new Controller();

function animate() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    main1.update();
    main1.draw();
    requestAnimationFrame(animate)
}

function updatePos() {
    main1.newPos();
}

animate()
setInterval(updatePos, 10)
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<img src="http://placekitten.com/50/50" id="character" style="display: none">
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code has two sets of velocities for the character: `this.speedY` gives the vertical velocity from jumping, and `this.dx` gives the horizontal velocity from controller input, while `this.dy` isn't actually used.  So if you want the character to stop from a collision, you could use something like this:

```js
        if (player.x < obstacle1.x + obstacle1.w &&
            player.x + obstacle1.w > obstacle1.x &&
            player.y < obstacle1.y + obstacle1.h &&
            player.y + player.h > obstacle1.y) {
            this.dx = this.speedY = 0;
        }
```

You probably want to unify the velocities into one pair of values, e.g. `this.dx` and `this.dy`, and adjust either when the player's velocity changes (from any action or gravity).

If you want to disable certain actions while the player is colliding, you might want to set a variable that you can use in the `update()` function.  For example:

```js
        this.isColliding =
            player.x < obstacle1.x + obstacle1.w &&
            player.x + obstacle1.w > obstacle1.x &&
            player.y < obstacle1.y + obstacle1.h &&
            player.y + player.h > obstacle1.y;
        if (this.isColliding) {
            this.dx = this.speedY = 0;
        }
```

As another note, `prevTime` and `isGrounded` should really be properties of the class (`this.prevTime`, etc.), not global variables.  And `time` could be declared local to `update()`, as it's not needed otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for the help edemaine. However, all this does it make the box fall slower when i hit the box. The animation I'm trying to create is a rigid body, so when the player hits the box, you can still move, but its like hitting a solid object. I've tried just getting the x coords and stopping the player when it hits the box, but it doesn't look natural :/

Comment: If you want to simulate a moving rigid body hitting a round fixed rigid body, then I believe the correct thing to do would be to flip the sign of the velocity: `this.dx = -this.dx; this.speedY = -this.speedY`. If you're hitting a square, you probably just want to negate the velocity in the dimension you hit. For example, if you hit a block from below, you probably just want to negate `speedY`.

Comment: I did this, and for some reason it's jumping??? it's acting really weirdly :/

Answer (score 0):

Collision detection in this way is not as simple as a single block of code. This is a good start to determine if the objects do collide but you will then need to pass that information to another function to handle the actions that should be taken based on the side of the collision. This is refered to as 'broad phase' and 'narrow phase'.

Note that there's is no, one perfect formula that handles every rectangle CD. You may find yourself needing to alter your main function to handle specific object within the game at some point because they have different properties.

Now I will provide you with a working example here using your code but I must highly recommend you don't continue piling all of your game objects into one class like you are doing. This is already making things difficult and will only make your game more complicated in the long run. You should break out you obstacles, lava, ground etc and give each their own class. I also notice that you are trying to put all of your CD into the class. This is sometimes ok but for what you are currently trying to accomplish I would have separate functions.

You'll notice in this snippet that the player actually enters into the ground a bit and the obstacles before going back to it's spot. The code overall is a bit finicky because of how it's written.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const characterImage = document.getElementById("character");
const level = 1;
canvas.width = document.body.scrollWidth;
canvas.height = 400//document.body.scrollHeight

let time; // Current time
let prevTime = Date.now(); // Store previous time
let player, obstacle1, obstacle2, ground;

class Main {
  constructor(x, y, w, h) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
    this.lives = 3;
    this.speedX = 0;
    this.speedY = 0;
    this.gravity = 0.01;
    this.jumping = false;
    //this.gravitySpeed = 0;
    this.jumpSpeed = -1.5; // How fast to jump upwards
    this.dx = 0;
    this.dy = 0;
    this.centerX = canvas.width / 2;
    this.centerY = canvas.height / 2;
  }
  draw() {
    if (this.x <= -0) {
      this.x = -0;
    }

    if (this.x >= canvas.width - 50) {
      this.x = canvas.width - 50;
    }

    player = {
      image: characterImage,
      x: this.x,
      y: this.y,
      w: 50,
      h: 50
    };

    obstacle1 = {
      x: this.centerX,
      y: canvas.height - 100,
      w: 50,
      h: 50
    };

    obstacle2 = {
      x: this.centerX + 50,
      y: canvas.height - 100,
      w: 50,
      h: 50
    };

    const lava = {};

    ground = {
      x: 0,
      y: canvas.height - 50,
      w: canvas.width,
      h: 50
    };

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "#9b7653";
    ctx.fillRect(ground.x, ground.y, ground.w, ground.h);
    ctx.closePath();

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "pink";
    ctx.fillRect(player.x, player.y, player.w, player.h);
    ctx.closePath();

    //obstacles
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "#df4759";
    ctx.fillRect(obstacle1.x, obstacle1.y, obstacle1.w, obstacle1.h);
    ctx.closePath();

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "#df4759";
    ctx.fillRect(obstacle2.x, obstacle2.y, obstacle2.w, obstacle2.h);
    ctx.closePath();
  }
  newPos() {
    this.gravitySpeed += this.gravity;
    this.x += this.speedX;
  }

  update() {
    // Calculate how much time has passed since last update
    time = Date.now();
    const deltaTime = time - prevTime;

    if (controller1.up && !this.jumping) {
      // Set the player y-speed to jump speed
      this.speedY = this.jumpSpeed;
      this.jumping = true; //prevents jumping while already in air
    }

    if (controller1.right) {
      this.dx += 0.7;
    }
    if (controller1.left) {
      this.dx -= 0.7;
    }
    
    this.y += this.speedY * deltaTime;
    this.y += this.gravity * deltaTime;

    this.speedY += this.gravity * deltaTime;
    this.x += this.dx;
    // this.y += this.dy;
    this.dx *= 0.9;
    this.dy *= 0.9;

    // Store the current time to use for calculation in next update
    prevTime = Date.now();
  }
}

class Controller {
  constructor() {
    this.up = false;
    this.right = false;
    this.down = false;
    this.left = false;

    let keyEvent = (e) => {
      if (e.code == "KeyW" || e.code == "ArrowUp" || e.code == "Space") {
        this.up = e.type == "keydown";
      }
      if (e.code == "KeyD" || e.code == "ArrowRight") {
        this.right = e.type == "keydown";
      }
      if (e.code == "KeyA" || e.code == "ArrowLeft") {
        this.left = e.type == "keydown";
      }
    };

    addEventListener("keydown", keyEvent);
    addEventListener("keyup", keyEvent);
    addEventListener("mousemove", keyEvent);
  }
}

function collision(player, obj) {
  if (
    player.x + player.w < obj.x ||
    player.x > obj.x + obj.w ||
    player.y + player.h < obj.y ||
    player.y > obj.y + obj.h
  ) {
    return;
  }
  this.narrowPhase(player, obj);
}
function narrowPhase(player, obj) {
  let playerTop_ObjBottom = Math.abs(player.y - (obj.y + obj.h));
  let playerRight_ObjLeft = Math.abs(player.x + player.w - obj.x);
  let playerLeft_ObjRight = Math.abs(player.x - (obj.x + obj.w));
  let playerBottom_ObjTop = Math.abs(player.y + player.h - obj.y);

  if (
    player.y <= obj.y + obj.h &&
    player.y + player.h > obj.y + obj.h &&
    playerTop_ObjBottom < playerRight_ObjLeft &&
    playerTop_ObjBottom < playerLeft_ObjRight
  ) {
    main1.y = obj.y + obj.h;
    main1.speedY = 0;
  }
  if (
    player.y + player.h >= obj.y &&
    player.y < obj.y &&
    playerBottom_ObjTop < playerRight_ObjLeft &&
    playerBottom_ObjTop < playerLeft_ObjRight
  ) {
    main1.y = obj.y - player.h - 0.05;
    main1.speedY = 0;
    main1.jumping = false;
  }
  if (
    player.x + player.w >= obj.x &&
    player.x < obj.x &&
    playerRight_ObjLeft < playerTop_ObjBottom &&
    playerRight_ObjLeft < playerBottom_ObjTop
  ) {
    main1.x = obj.x - obj.w - 0.05;
    main1.dx = 0;
  }
  if (
    player.x <= obj.x + obj.w &&
    player.x + player.w > obj.x + obj.w &&
    playerLeft_ObjRight < playerTop_ObjBottom &&
    playerLeft_ObjRight < playerBottom_ObjTop
  ) {
    main1.x = obj.x + obj.w + 0.05;
    main1.dx = 0;
  }
}

let main1 = new Main(50, canvas.height - 250, 50, 50);
let controller1 = new Controller();

function animate() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  main1.draw();
  main1.update();
  collision(player, obstacle2);
  collision(player, obstacle1);
  collision(player, ground);
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

function updatePos() {
  main1.newPos();
}

animate();
setInterval(updatePos, 10);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

I'm going to provide a second example where I've removed the objects from the main class and made each there own. I also removed the `dx` and `dy` as I think there was confusion about those and mixing them with `speedX` and `speedY`. On another note in your `newPos()` function you have `this.x += this.speedX;` but you also have that in the update function so in reality your are doubling it. I don't think that;s what you wanted.

You'll see in this example the collision is much smoother

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const characterImage = document.getElementById("character");
const level = 1;
canvas.width = document.body.scrollWidth;
canvas.height = 400//document.body.scrollHeight

let time; // Current time
let prevTime = Date.now(); // Store previous time

class Entity {
  constructor(x, y, w, h) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
    this.lives = 3;
    this.speedX = 0;
    this.speedY = 0;
    this.gravity = 0.01;
    this.jump = false;
    this.jumpSpeed = -1.5; // How fast to jump upwards
    this.centerX = canvas.width / 2;
    this.centerY = canvas.height / 2;
  }
  draw() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "pink";
    ctx.fillRect(player.x, player.y, player.w, player.h);
    ctx.closePath();
  }
  newPos() {
    this.gravitySpeed += this.gravity;
    //this.x += this.speedX;
  }
  collision() {
    if (this.x <= -0) {
      this.x = -0;
    }
    if (this.x >= canvas.width - 50) {
      this.x = canvas.width - 50;
    }
  }
  update() {
    // Calculate how much time has passed since last update
    time = Date.now();
    const deltaTime = time - prevTime;

    if (controller1.up && !this.jump) {
      this.speedY = this.jumpSpeed;
      this.jump = true;
    }
    if (controller1.right) {
      this.speedX += 0.7;
    }
    if (controller1.left) {
      this.speedX -= 0.7;
    }
    
    this.y += this.speedY * deltaTime;
    this.y += this.gravity * deltaTime;

    this.speedY += this.gravity * deltaTime;
    this.x += this.speedX;
    this.speedX *= 0.9;
    this.speedY *= 0.9;
    // Store the current time to use for calculation in next update
    prevTime = Date.now();
  }
}

class Obstacle {
  constructor(x, y, w, h) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
    this.color = '#df4759';
  }
  draw() {
    ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
    ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
  }
}
/*
class Lava {
  constructor(x, y, w, h) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
    this.color = 'red';
  }
  draw() {
    ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
    ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
  }
}
*/
class Ground {
  constructor(x, y, w, h) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
    this.color = '#8a6c4e';
  }
  draw() {
    ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
    ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
  }
}

class Controller {
  constructor() {
    this.up = false;
    this.right = false;
    this.down = false;
    this.left = false;

    let keyEvent = (e) => {
      if (e.code == "KeyW" || e.code == "ArrowUp" || e.code == "Space") {
        this.up = e.type == "keydown";
      }
      if (e.code == "KeyD" || e.code == "ArrowRight") {
        this.right = e.type == "keydown";
      }
      if (e.code == "KeyA" || e.code == "ArrowLeft") {
        this.left = e.type == "keydown";
      }
    };

    addEventListener("keydown", keyEvent);
    addEventListener("keyup", keyEvent);
    addEventListener("mousemove", keyEvent);
  }
}

function collision(player, obj) {
  if (
    player.x + player.w < obj.x ||
    player.x > obj.x + obj.w ||
    player.y + player.h < obj.y ||
    player.y > obj.y + obj.h
  ) {
    return;
  }
  this.narrowPhase(player, obj);
}

function narrowPhase(player, obj) {
  let playerTop_ObjBottom = Math.abs(player.y - (obj.y + obj.h));
  let playerRight_ObjLeft = Math.abs(player.x + player.w - obj.x);
  let playerLeft_ObjRight = Math.abs(player.x - (obj.x + obj.w));
  let playerBottom_ObjTop = Math.abs(player.y + player.h - obj.y);

  if (
    player.y <= obj.y + obj.h &&
    player.y + player.h > obj.y + obj.h &&
    playerTop_ObjBottom < playerRight_ObjLeft &&
    playerTop_ObjBottom < playerLeft_ObjRight
  ) {
    player.y = obj.y + obj.h;
    player.speedY = 0;
  }
  if (
    player.y + player.h >= obj.y &&
    player.y < obj.y &&
    playerBottom_ObjTop < playerRight_ObjLeft &&
    playerBottom_ObjTop < playerLeft_ObjRight
  ) {
    player.y = obj.y - player.h;
   // player.dy = 0;
    player.speedY = 0;
    player.jump = false;
  }
  if (
    player.x + player.w >= obj.x &&
    player.x < obj.x &&
    playerRight_ObjLeft < playerTop_ObjBottom &&
    playerRight_ObjLeft < playerBottom_ObjTop
  ) {
    player.x = obj.x - obj.w;
    player.speedX = 0;
  }
  if (
    player.x <= obj.x + obj.w &&
    player.x + player.w > obj.x + obj.w &&
    playerLeft_ObjRight < playerTop_ObjBottom &&
    playerLeft_ObjRight < playerBottom_ObjTop
  ) {
    player.x = obj.x + obj.w;
    player.speedX = 0;
  }
}

let obstacle1 = new Obstacle(canvas.width/2, canvas.height - 100, 50, 50)
let obstacle2 = new Obstacle(canvas.width/2 + 50, canvas.height - 100, 50, 50)
let ground = new Ground(0, canvas.height - 50, canvas.width, 50)
let player = new Entity(50, canvas.height - 250, 50, 50);
let controller1 = new Controller();

function animate() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  collision(player, obstacle2);
  collision(player, obstacle1);
  collision(player, ground);
  player.draw();
  player.update();
  ground.draw();
  obstacle1.draw();
  obstacle2.draw();
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

function updatePos() {
  player.newPos();
}

animate();
setInterval(updatePos, 10);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```